# How do I add a matrix constraint `Ax=b` to a Pyomo model efficiently?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I want to add the constraints `Ax=b` to a Pyomo model with my `numpy` arrays `A` and `b` as efficient as possible. Unfortunately, the performance is very bad currently. For the following example

```py
    import time
    import numpy as np
    import pyomo.environ as pyo

    start = time.time()
    rows = 287
    cols = 2765
    A = np.random.rand(rows, cols)
    b = np.random.rand(rows)
    mdl = pyo.ConcreteModel()
    mdl.rows = range(rows)
    mdl.cols = range(cols)
    mdl.A = A
    mdl.b = b
    mdl.x_var = pyo.Var(mdl.cols, bounds=(0.0, None))

    mdl.constraints = pyo.ConstraintList()
    [mdl.constraints.add(sum(mdl.A[row, col] * mdl.x_var[col] for col in mdl.cols) <= mdl.b[row]) for row in mdl.rows]

    mdl.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(mdl.x_var[col] for col in mdl.cols), sense=pyo.minimize)
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

is takes almost 30 seconds because of the add statement and the huge amount of columns. Is it possible to pass `A`, `x`, and `b` directly and fast instead of adding it row by row?

Comment: 2765 ≠ huge. Nowadays we routinely solve models with tens of millions of columns.

Comment: Note that you generate a completely dense model. Almost all practical models are (very) sparse. So this test is likely not very relevant.

Comment: I understand that practical models are sparser than this one. Nevertheless, if you say that the model is far away from huge, why does it take almost 30 seconds? Isn't there a more efficient way to pass this model to pyomo?

Answer (score 2):

The main thing that is slowing down your construction above is the fact that you are building the constraint list elements *within* a list comprehension, which is unnecessary and causes a lot of bloat.

This line:

```
[mdl.constraints.add(sum(mdl.A[row, col] * mdl.x_var[col] for col in mdl.cols) <= mdl.b[row]) for row in mdl.rows]
```

Constructs a *list of the captured results* of each `ConstraintList.add()` expression, which is a "rich" return.  That list is an unnecessary byproduct of the loop you desire to do over the `add()` function.  Just change your generation scheme to either a loop or a generator (by using parens) to avoid that capture, as such:

```
(mdl.constraints.add(sum(mdl.A[row, col] * mdl.x_var[col] for col in mdl.cols) <= mdl.b[row]) for row in mdl.rows)
```

And the model construction time drops to about 0.02 seconds.